# SQLite order by equivalent query for MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
   SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY username='eldho', username ASC
```

Can somebody help me to write the the **SQLite** equivalent query for the above **MySQL** query ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is very basic standard SQL, so there shouldn't be any difference at all, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT username
FROM users
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN username = 'eldho' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    username;
```

Comment: I would suggest rollback your previous. what you say ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma The equality returns 0 for false and 1 for true.  Hence, what I wrote about is the translation to SQLite.  As to whether the OP actually _wants_ this ordrering, I really don't know.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5971e/10 - your posted answer doesn't work in SQLite

Comment: you mixed up `THEN 1 ELSE 0`. This should have been `THEN 0 ELSE 1` so that `'eldho'` is on the top of the list.

Answer (score -1):

This puts `'eldho'` on top of the list then the rest is sorted alphabetically.

```
SELECT username
FROM users
ORDER BY
    CASE username
        WHEN 'eldho' 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5971e/9

Comment: I'm sorry - what do you mean?

Comment: I already gave this answer 15 minutes before you posted.  And you removed one of the sort conditions, so what you posted isn't even correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, check my sqlfiddle and try out your answer there. The answer you posted doesn't sort the way OP wanted it.